# Why OpenGL cut off polygons (even if this settings is disabled)?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-compat

[*I read similar suggested questions and their solutions, but could not find an answer*.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071539/inbuilt-polygon-clipping-in-opengl)

I'm trying to draw a scene with an isometric view in OpenGL.

Draw func:

```cpp
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glRotatef(atan(0.5f) * 180.0f / PI, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(-45.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
    
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
```

In the end, I get this result. The camera does have an isometric projection, but for some reason polygons are clipped.

[image: Screen 1]

If I add `glTranslatef(-0.8f, 0, -0.8f)` before drawing the quad, the result is as follows:

[image: Screen 2]

The problem is that I don't apply any optimization to OpenGL render. But why do polygons have to be cut off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The polygons are clipped by the near or far plane of the viewing volume.

When you do not set a projection matrix, then view space, clip space and normalized device space are the same. The normalized device space is a unique cube with the left, bottom, near of (-1, -1, -1) and right, top, far of (1, 1, 1). All the geometry which is not inside this cube is clipped.

[image]

Actually you draw a quad with a side length of 1. One vertex of the quad is at the origin of the view (0, 0, 0). The quad is rotated around the origin by [`glRotate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml). Since the length of the diagonal of the quad is `sqrt(2.0)`, one vertex of the rotated quad is clipped by either the near plane or the far plane.

If you construct and rotate a quad whose center is (0, 0 ,0), it will not be clipped, because the length form the center to each vertex is `sqrt(2.0)/2.0`. That is less than 1 (distance to near and far plane form the center of the viewing volume)

```cpp
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.0f, -0.5f);
glVertex3f( 0.5f, 0.0f, -0.5f);
glVertex3f( 0.5f, 0.0f,  0.5f);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.0f,  0.5f);
glEnd();
```

respectively

```cpp
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glRotatef(atan(0.5f) * 180.0f / PI, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(-45.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

glTranslate(-0.5f, 0.0f, -0.5f);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glEnd();
```

Alternatively you can set an [Orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Orthographic_projection), which enlarges the viewing volume by [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml):

```cpp
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -2.0, 2.0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glRotatef(atan(0.5f) * 180.0f / PI, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(-45.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);    

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glEnd();
```

Comment: I used your suggestion about `glOrtho` and it really solved the problem. Thanks.